# When will C release statically allocated variable declarations

Tags: c

I'm writing an application that is heap sensitive as it's running on a small MCU. I have a function that declares an output type struct to store data which will then write it to a string, and thus, is no longer required. As per below, it's statically defined (not `malloc()`'d).

Will C free the heap allocation once exiting `function()` or should I `malloc` the variable and `free` it when it's no longer required?

```
#define INFO_SIZE 99

char *info = NULL; 

void function() { 
    struct type_a outvar = HELPER_MACRO(info, INFO_SIZE);
    convert_to_string(&outvar, "helloworld"); 
    // delete outvar??
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no heap allocation in the posted code.

Answer (score 4):

The variable in your example is not static, it's a variable with [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) which means that yes, it will be destroyed at the end of its enclosing scope - at the end of the function call in your example.

Comment: Automatic variable are allocated in stack. Stack is shared between all functions in progress. On MCU, stack size is generally very limited (a few kB). So, it is not a good idea to allocate to much big objects on stack.

Comment: @Jezz on uCs it bad to use dynamic allocation as well. And that is one of the reasons why uC programming is so challenging

Answer (score 1):

```
void function() { 
  struct type_a outvar = HELPER_MACRO(info, INFO_SIZE);
```

Variable `outvar` is allocated when the function is called (most [all modern] implementations use stack) and destroyed when function exits. The variable is initialized every time the function is called.

```
void function() { 
  static struct type_a outvar = HELPER_MACRO(info, INFO_SIZE);
```

Variable `outvar` is allocated in in the global (static) storage with the local scope and **not** destroyed when function exits. The variable is initialized before the main is called. The initializer has to be a constant expression.

```
void function() { 
  struct type_a * outvar = malloc(...);
```

Variable `outvar` is allocated on the stack and initialized to the address of the allocated block on the heap. The variable is destroyed on function exit, but the allocated memory is not freed automatically. It has to be freed by the programmer.

Comment: No — in your example with `static struct type_a outvar`, the variable is allocated with static duration ([C11 §6.2.4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p3)) but with [block](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p3) scope (where the block is the body of the function) — and _not_ with global scope as you state.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I meant that the most implementation will place them in the .bss or .data segments  which are global. But of course the scope is local to the function. Edited